# How to read process memory at a specific address?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, memory-management

I want to read 64 bytes from a process's memory starting at a known memory location. I wrote the following `C++` code for this purpose:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    LPCVOID Address = (LPCVOID)0x0000029FC0C41FF0; // the memory address where I want to read from
    byte buffer[64];
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, 13868);  // the process ID of the process


    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, Address, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

    const int siz_ar = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(int);   // the rest is trying to display the bytes read on stdout

    for (int i = 0; i < siz_ar; ++i)
        cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << buffer[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

It does not work and produces the following strange string in console out:

```
0╠ 0╠ 0╠ 0╠ 0╠ 0╠ 0╠ 0╠
```

How can I correct this program to read raw bytes from the specific memory address from a specific process (specified by the process ID)?

Comment: Your code doesn't perform any error-checking (e.g. checking that `OpenProcess` succeeded, that `ReadProcessMemory` succeeded, etc). **Do that first**.

Comment: Maybe it's too early in the morning, but where does the `hex` variable in the for loop come from? Also, in production code, `using namespace std;` is frowned upon, because of namespace pollution. See here for details : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236404/what-is-using-namespace-pollution

Comment: The next step is to add error checking. Read the docs for the two api functions that you call, which tell you how to check for errors.

Comment: @schaiba it's `std::hex`, so yes, too early! ;-)

Comment: As an aside: Calculating how many `int`s fit into `buffer` is all fine and well, but you still read it byte per byte. You should either reassemble `sizeof int` consecutive bytes into an `int` or cast `buffer` to an `int*` and walk it like that.

Comment: You need to cast `buffer[i]` to `int` when passing it to `cout`. `operator<<` treats `byte` (aka `unsigned char`) the same as a `char`, which is why you are not seeing your hex values correctly. That said, your `buffer` contains bytes `CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC`, which is a common byte pattern for uninitialized stack memory, which means your `ReadProcessMemory()` call is failing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `byte` is probably an alias for `char`. If you pass a `char` to `std::cout`, it will print it not as a number, but as a character. Cast to a non-character type like `unsigned int` first.

You will then notice that it only outputs `0xCC`, which is a common marker for uninitialized memory (`╠` in some codepages). Do error checking on your calls to find out why `buffer` never gets filled.